# how to make href linkable with ajax without reload the page

Tags: ajax

I have this link:

```
<a href="/follow/78" class="follow_all_button" onclick="followUser(); return true">follow</a>
```

when the user click on its just refresh the page and do the follow function.

it there is to do the follow without reload the page?

sorry I am so week in Ajax, and really need help

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Ajax to stop the browser from reloading.

Just change `return true` to `return false`, and you will cancel the default browser behaviour of following links.

If the `followUser` function makes an Ajax request or not won't make a difference.

Comment: No, the followUser function just to change the url to the unfollow url

Comment: @ManMann If my answer did not solve your problem you will probably need to post your `followUser` function for anyone to be able to help.